# didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation not called after swipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, swipe, ios-4.2, landscape-portrait

I've got the following problem:

I have a UITabBarController that displays different information in each tab about e.g. a CD. The user can use UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape to see just the cover. To go to the next CD the user can go back and select a new CD and information are displayed again in UITabBarController. (All this works fine.)
Additionally, to make it easier watching a lot of CDs, it's possible to go to the next CD with a swipe gesture (in landscape or portrait orientation). Then I just change the tabBarController.viewControllers and set the viewControllers that display information of the new CD. 
The Problem is now: after I swiped to the next CD the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method is never called again and I cannot change from landscape mode to portrait mode. The swiping gesture keeps the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method from being called! I only have this problem with iOS 4.2.1. With iOS 5 everything works perfectly!

Does anyone know what is going on with iOS 4?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation YES into all the base controllers of TABBARView controller

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in every class already returns YES. I also don't think that this could be the reason, because changing from portrait to landscape mode always works. It just doesn't work after swiping in iOS 4.2.1. In iOS 5 I have NO problems.